# Is it better to use v-on directive or watch method to detect a change in a form field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to detect a change in a form's field, as I understand in `Vue` there are two ways to do that:

1. via `v-on` directive
2. via `watch` method

Which one would you recommend to use? Are they the same in terms of how much memory they use? Why would I prefer one to the other?

**UPDATE**

Just to explain what I need: I have a form and I need to send a Google Analytics `ga` event out each time somebody enters something in the field and then leaves it. `v-on` or `watch`?

Comment: You better use `v-on` in most cases. `watch` will be triggered on every data change, not just key strokes. Using `v-on` you are also able to pass an event object to your handler. Besides that, I'd say that event-based interactions with form inputs are very common practice. I don't think one needs to reinvent that.

Answer (score 4):

You understand incorrectly. Use `v-on` to detect **events** like `change` or `input` on a form field. Use `watch` to detect **changes in a reactive data item** (`data`, `computed`, or `prop`).

If you use `v-model` on a field, you are implicitly using `v-on` to detect `input` (or `change` if using the `.lazy` modifier) and copy that value into a data item. If you are tempted to add another `v-on` to detect changes, you probably should `watch` the data that is already changing with the form field. The exception is if you specifically need to know that the change came from the form field and there might be other ways it could change.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think I understand — What if I just want to send an event to google analytics each time someone inputs data into a form field or selects an option from a menu in the form?

Comment: How do you think you would set up the `watch`?